# github sees wrong username over ssh (Windows)

Tags: authentication, github, ssh, push

**Edit**: it turned out to be some issue of git on Windows.
The problem is not reproduced on a Linux system.

I'm trying to clone my github repository.

I followed [official github's instructions on setting up an SSH access](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey?platform=windows). Key verification is successful:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi 1234ru! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

And the repository url looks correct:

```
$ git remote get-url --push origin
git@github.com:1234ru/<my-repo>.git
```

The `clone` command fails:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:1234ru/<myrepo>.git
1234ru@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I don't understand how can the `ssh -T` response be OK and `git clone` be rejected at the same time.

Comment: authentication is one thing... authorization is a different thing. Github knows who you are now, you might not be allowed to do whatever it is you are requesting you want to do.

Comment: @Toerktumlare, that would be very strange. This is my own repository, and I didn't set any specific security restrictions on it. Why wouldn't it let me push?

Comment: Are you *sure* you followed all the instructions *exactly*.

Comment: @topsail, yes, I am. Otherwise I wouldn't pass `ssh -T` check, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to pass ssh -T and not be able to push. You just did it ;)

Comment: @1234ru that i can't answer since i dont have access to your account so that i can look. With the info you have provided, we can only guess or be vague. And i dont like guessing, so im vague instead.

Comment: @topsail it turned out to be some issue of git on Windows. I've just tried to do the same things on a Linux machine, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The whole issue was because of altered git's `core.sshCommand` setting, which contained explicit username:

```
$ git config core.sshCommand
ssh -l 1234ru
```

That made `git` commands to connect to Github using `1234ru` username, *not* `git` username, as it should, which led to access denial.

Reading error message carefully actually makes it clear:

> **1234ru**@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

It should be **git**. If it's not, and the remote URL is correct - check out your `core.sshCommand` (note the scope as well):

```
git config --show-scope core.sshCommand
```

If it looks weird, just unset it:

```
git config --unset core.sshCommand
```